# Repeatedly incrementing a DateTime value within a loop?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append a timestamp to each line of a file. So far this works fine and I get the following:

0,16.4,34,8120,2814,0,0,0,2.44,0,0,8192,200,10/08/2020 12:46:30
1,2.34,34,8120,2813,0,0,0,2.44,0,0,8192,200,10/08/2020 12:46:30

However, I want this to keep incrementing by 30 seconds.

I am using this variable time in my script:

```
$parsedtime = [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($timeformat,'yyMMddHHmm',$null)
$parsedtime
```

I can get it to add normally:

```
$parsedtime2 = $parsedtime.AddSeconds(30);
```

But, I cant get it keep adding 30 seconds to each timestamp:

```
ForEach ($_ in $file) 
{
$_ + "," + ($parsedtime).AddSeconds(30)
}
```

Is it possible to keep looping the AddSeconds inside of a ForEach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign back to the variable:

```
ForEach ($_ in $file) 
{
    $parsedtime = $parsedtime.AddSeconds(30)
    $_ + "," + $parsedtime
}
```

Alternatively, track how many iterations you've had:

```
$i = 0
ForEach ($_ in $file) 
{
    $i++
    $_ + "," + ($parsedtime).AddSeconds(30 * i)
}
```

Comment: WAAAAhhh that was it.... I been staring at this too long haha. thank you so much, worked like a charm.